# Enumerate bullets not appearing

Tags: beamer, lists, enumerate

In the past (on a different computer) I have used the beamer package to make presentations and the enumerate environment has worked fine. However, now when I use the enumerate environment, the nice little numbered circles are not appearing. Does anyone know what the issue is? I recently installed MiKTEX 2.9 and I have updated it.

update:
@asia1281

I have tried doing something really simple like:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[ball]
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Example}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Item 1
    \item Item 2
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and the numbered balls do not print on the pdf file.

Thanks

update: 
@asia1281 
Here is the entire log:

https://docs.google.com/a/binghamton.edu/document/d/1jNkbrzWMy4bAA_U_Luj6_5ZN5MLW0hyuyXwKBn4aAIc/edit?pli=1

Thanks!

Comment: this one is pretty hard to diagnose as you've given it...could we see some code?  maybe even a minimal example of what you tried?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). The `enumerate` environment produces numbers (1., 2., ...) by default, and `itemize` produces bullets.  The code that is producing the _numbered circles_ is probably the issue. So, please compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: @PeterGrill: the document class is `beamer` (it is on the question) and some options (`circle` or `ball`) for the `enumerate items` template place the numbers inside little circles.

Comment: Do you get any warnings or errors in the log? What does the output actually look like? Do you get balls without numbers or nothing at all? Can you put `\listfiles` as the first line of the document and post the output of the file list?

Comment: @AlanMunn I have never used \listfiles before, where will the output be?

Comment: It should show up in the log file. The relevant part will begin with something like:
`*File List*
beamer.cls    2011/09/12 development version 3.14 A class for typesetting presentations (rcs-revision 70f9d8411e54)`

Comment: You can edit your question to add it.

Comment: See if you can view it properly in acrobat reader.

Comment: You have some very old things among some not so old things. In particular graphics.cfg (1.5) vs. my 1.9; Can you try to update MikTeX again, and also see if you have any local versions of things in your local texmf folder. (I don't have MikTeX, so I can't tell you exactly where to look.)

Comment: @YiannisLazarides:  I have tried that, no luck

Comment: @AlanMunn: Thanks for the help. I will try to run the updater again

Comment: The log file you've posted is not the log file from the minimal document you've posted, but from some other document. And now @GonzaloMedina has found the problem. But then your minimal document *must* work, no?

Answer (score 5):

The problem comes from the package `IEEEtrantools.sty` which internally redefines the `enumerate` and `itemize` environments. To avoid the redefinition, don't load this package or, if you need the package for something specific, load it using the `retainorgcmds` package option:

```
\usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools}
```

to prevent the redefinitions that this package does to the `enumerate` environment. A minimal example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools}

\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[ball]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Example}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Item 1
    \item Item 2
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Matt: you're welcome! Next time, however, use a "true" minimal example reproducing the problem; the one you posted works OK; it was only through the .log file (from another document) that the problem could be detected.

Comment: @Matt if you happen to return to this site, it would be courteous of you to accept his answer : )

Answer (score 2):

i don't use miktex, but do you know what exactly it is compiling with?  is it latex? or pdflatex?  or something completely different?  are you sure you're viewing the pdf and not the dvi?  when i compile your example with pdflatex, the resulting pdf shows up fine.  when i compile with latex to make the dvi, i don't get the shapes:
[image: dvi]

but when i take that dvi and make it a pdf with `dvipdf` the shapes appear:
[image: pdf]

Comment: I am using pdflatex, and when I view the pdf file using acrobat the balls are still not showing up.

Comment: @Matt would you mind posting the log that appears when you compile?  when i use `acroread` to view the pdf instead of `evince` i can still see the images like in my second picture.